# How invoke APEX method from custom button

Tags: apex-code

I have add custom button for salesforce's Sales application's 'Opportunities' tab. Once press that button I want to navigate some new tab (I have done it by adding proper URL) and execute following Apex method. How can execute this method. Thanks.

```
public class JobService {

private JobDao job_dao = new JobDao();

public void insertJob() {
Job__c newJob = new Job__c();
job_dao.insertJob(newJob); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have accomplished this task as following way,

Add following java script codes to, custom button's javaScript 'onClick' section.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

//Get Opportunity id 
var opId= "{!Opportunity.Id}";

//Call insertJob method by passing that Opportunity id 
sforce.apex.execute("JobService","insertJob",{op_id:opId});

//Redirect to that tab 
window.location = 'https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0G/o';
```

Note:

- Thank you very much for Adam & Jeremy Ross for their guide, those are
  very much helpful to me.
- Please add some comment if any one know, how    can I retrieve
  Opportunity' object rather than retrieve    'Opportunity.Id', thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of options:

**VF Page**

Create a VF page. In the page's controller, call your Apex method, then forward user to the new tab

**JavaScript**

Expose a simple web service that calls your apex Method. Make the button an "onclick javascript" button and call the web service (see [Exposing Apex Classes as REST Web Services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_rest.htm) and [Apex in AJAX](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_and_ajax.htm) for how to do this). Forward the user to the new tab.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Ross! Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try this. But I have not created any VF page (tab), it was generated by salesforce wizard. Navigate to this newly created tab, url is "https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0G/o". I want to add some records that tab page. With manually clicking to this tab I can do it fine. But I want to add that record with Apex and after add that records, I want to navigate to this tab (that mean after execute above mention apex code I, want to navigate that to tab). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a lean Visualforce page with Opportunity as your controller and a custom class as an extension:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="RedirectClass" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

The extension (Apex) can look like the following:

```
// On load, action="{!redirect}" takes us here
public PageReference redirect()
{
    return Page.YourVisualforcePageWithATab;
}
```

Go to: Name|Setup|Customize|Opportunities|Buttons and Links| New

Select Visualforce Page in Content Source and then this visualforce "redirect" page you just created in the Content field. That should do it.

Comment: Hi Adam! Many thanks for your freed back. Currently I have not created any VF page (tab), it was generated by salesforce wizard. Navigate to this newly created tab, url is "https://ap1.salesforce.com/a0G/o". I want to add some records that tab page. With manually clicking to this tab I can do it fine. But I want to add that record with Apex and after add that records, I want to navigate to this tab (that mean after execute above mention apex code I, want to navigate that to tab). Thanks.